# Java - Edit existing JSON file

Tags: java

Hey I was wondering if it is possible to edit an existing json I know the location off.
So lets say that the location is C:\Something.json
then how do I edit it ??.

Thanks

Comment: Pls try some code.. And post for doubt

Answer (score 1):

If you want to edit complex JSON structure I would recommend using [GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) library. You can then perform the following steps :

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String yourfilecontents; //read contents from File
```

1) read JSON File and convert it into an object structure.

```
 YourObject obj = gson.fromJson(yourfilecontents, YourObject.class);
```

2) Modify the object as per your requirement.

```
obj.field1(newValue);
```

3) Convert the object into JSON

```
String newJson = gson.toJson(obj);
```

4) Write the JSON (newJson) back to the file

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very unprecise, but here are some tips, you can:

- Open the JSON file with your favourite notepad
- Use [`java.io.File` API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) to open the file
- Use [some JSON Java API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/json-1973242.html)

Answer (score 0):

To transform/filter JSON, especially in case of large files, it isn't a good idea to load the whole file to memory and use object mapping at all. Prefer stream oriented parsing and generating. For example, both Gson and Jackson support such technique. To illustrate the idea I use small, fast and GC-free library https://github.com/anatolygudkov/green-jelly. I've taken a question [Loop and edit json file in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59122190/loop-and-edit-json-file-in-java) The code renames all property names "div" to "b-div"

```
import org.green.jelly.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.io.Writer;

public class Transformation {

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException {
        final String inputContent = "{  \n" +
            "   \"html\":{  \n" +
            "      \"child\":[  \n" +
            "         {  \n" +
            "            \"head\":{  \n" +
            "\n" +
            "            }\n" +
            "         },\n" +
            "         {  \n" +
            "            \"body\":{  \n" +
            "               \"child\":[  \n" +
            "                  {  \n" +
            "                     \"div\":{  \n" +
            "                        \"id\":\"intk\",\n" +
            "                        \"class\":\"akagen-row b-table\",\n" +
            "                        \"child\":[  \n" +
            "                           {  \n" +
            "                              \"div\":{  \n" +
            "                                 \"id\":\"aaaaa\",\n" +
            "                                 \"title\":\"bbbbbbb\",\n" +
            "                                 \"class\":\"akagen-cell\"\n" +
            "                              }\n" +
            "                           }\n" +
            "                        ]\n" +
            "                     }\n" +
            "                  },\n" +
            "                  {  \n" +
            "                     \"div\":{  \n" +
            "                        \"class\":\"akagen-row b-table\",\n" +
            "                        \"child\":[  \n" +
            "                           {  \n" +
            "                              \"div\":{  \n" +
            "                                 \"class\":\"akagen-cell\"\n" +
            "                              }\n" +
            "                           },\n" +
            "                           {  \n" +
            "                              \"div\":{  \n" +
            "                                 \"class\":\"akagen-cell\"\n" +
            "                              }\n" +
            "                           },\n" +
            "                           {  \n" +
            "                              \"div\":{  \n" +
            "                                 \"class\":\"akagen-cell\"\n" +
            "                              }\n" +
            "                           }\n" +
            "                        ]\n" +
            "                     }\n" +
            "                  }\n" +
            "               ]\n" +
            "            }\n" +
            "         }\n" +
            "      ]\n" +
            "   }\n" +
            "}";

        final Reader input = new StringReader(inputContent); // replace by FileReader
        final Writer output = new StringWriter(); // replace by FileWriter

        final JsonGenerator generator = new JsonGenerator();
        generator.setOutput(new AppendableWriter<>(output));

        final JsonParser parser = new JsonParser().setListener(new JsonParserListener() {
            @Override
            public void onJsonStarted() {
                generator.reset();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(final String error, final int position) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onJsonEnded() {
                generator.eoj();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onObjectStarted() {
                generator.startObject();
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onObjectMember(final CharSequence name) {
                if ("div".contentEquals(name)) {
                    generator.objectMember("b-div");
                } else {
                    generator.objectMember(name);
                }
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onObjectEnded() {
                generator.endObject();
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onArrayStarted() {
                generator.startArray();
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onArrayEnded() {
                generator.startArray();
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onStringValue(final CharSequence data) {
                generator.stringValue(data);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onNumberValue(final JsonNumber number) {
                generator.numberValue(number);
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onTrueValue() {
                generator.trueValue();
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onFalseValue() {
                generator.falseValue();
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onNullValue() {
                generator.nullValue();
                return true;
            }
        });

        final CharArrayCharSequence buffer = new CharArrayCharSequence(1024 * 8);
        int length;
        while ((length = input.read(buffer.getChars())) != -1) {
            buffer.setLength(length);
            parser.parse(buffer);
        }
        parser.eoj();

        System.out.println(output.toString());
    }
}
```

Performance of such lightweight technique of transformation is almost the highest in terms of both CPU utilization and memory footprint you can reach in Java (with no tricks like SIMD over JNI).