# Iterate all json object and replace values

Tags: java, json, iterator

I have following JSON:

```
{  
   "data":{  
      "attributes":{  
         "external-event-url":"http://example.com",
         "is-sponsors-enabled":"true",
         "is-ticketing-enabled":"true",
         "timezone":"UTC",
         "name":"${name_variable}",
         "ends-at":"2020-01-02T23:59:59.123456+00:00",
         "starts-at":"2020-01-01T23:59:59.123456+00:00"
      },
      "type":"event"
   }
}
```

I have to iterate through json objects and replace the value of variable starts with `${` e.g. `${name_variable}`
and new json should be in same format(with replace value of variable mentioned `${}`)

How do i iterate such complex Json object and replace the values in variables

I've tried below code but not working as expected:

```
public Map<String, String> mapfillData(String jsonstr) {
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonstr);
        String[] keys = JSONObject.getNames(jsonObject);

        for (String key : keys) {
            try {
                if (jsonObject.get(key).toString().startsWith("${")) {
                    map.put(key, System.getProperty(jsonObject.get(key).toString()
                            .replace("${", "").replace("}", "")));
                } else {
                    if(isJSONValid(jsonObject.get(key).toString())){
                        mapfillData(jsonObject.get(key).toString());
                    }else{
                        map.put(key, jsonObject.get(key).toString());
                    }
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        System.err.printf(jsonstr + " is not valid Json", e);
    }
    return map;
}
```

To check whether its a valid JSON Object

```
public boolean isJSONValid(String test) {
    try {
        new JSONObject(test);
    } catch (JSONException ex) {
        // edited, to include @Arthur's comment
        // e.g. in case JSONArray is valid as well...
        try {
            new JSONArray(test);
        } catch (JSONException ex1) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: "How do i iterate such complex Json object and replace the values in variables", recursively. If it's a JSONObject then descend into it and iterate over its children if the child is a JSONObject then recurse.

Comment: @xtratic, That is what i tried to implement the same logic. but can't figure where i committed mistake.

Comment: Ask yourself if it wouldn't be better to just do the replacement on the JSON text as a whole. But if you decide not, then it's a better idea to first convert the JSON to an object, and then call a recursive method that accepts a JSONObject, not a string, and avoid all the conversions from string to object and back.

Comment: Please post all of your code. What does isJSONValid() look like?

Comment: @StvnBrkdll, Updated. this method used to check whether that value of particular key is JSON object or not if yes then recursion

Comment: Frankly, if possible, I'd go with a different JSON library like [Jackson](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core). The library you're using seems kinda limited and is making it more complicated than it needs to be to do this simple task of testing if a JSON node is an Object or not.

Comment: I'd suggest you to take a look at very similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23298341/java-edit-existing-json-file/59183538#59183538  It renames a property name, but you easily can modify it to change string property value in onStringValue callback.

Comment: I found desire answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/26127684/7389507

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that while you are trying to recursively process the JSON, at each level of recursion, you're processing a *different* JSON document and writing data into a *different* `Map`.

Your function takes a string and then parses it into a `JSONObject`. You create a `Map` to hold some data. The first time through `mapfillData`, you're only going to find one key, `data`. Then, assuming that your `if` logic works correctly (I didn't try to run it), you're going to render the contents of `data` into another string and recursively call `mapfillData`.

Now you're in the second call to `mapfillData`, and you create another `Map`. This time through you find `attributes` and call `mapfillData` a third time. In this third invocation, you find some variables and replace them when writing the values to `Map`. At the end of the function, you return the `Map`, but the caller (the second invocation of `mapfillData`) doesn't do anything with the returned `Map`, and all your data is lost.

I would:

- Parse the JSON once, then recurse through the JSONObject structure. In other words, the recursive function should take JSONObject.
- Just replace the JSON elements in-place.
- Or, if you want to flatten the elements and collect them into a `Map`, then instantiate the `Map` up-front and pass it into the recursive function.

Answer (score 0):

To convert more easily, you can use the [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/) lib to do the hard stuff:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String jsonString = "{  
   "data":{  
      "attributes":{  
         "external-event-url":"http://example.com",
         "is-sponsors-enabled":"true",
         "is-ticketing-enabled":"true",
         "timezone":"UTC",
         "name":"${name_variable}",
         "ends-at":"2020-01-02T23:59:59.123456+00:00",
         "starts-at":"2020-01-01T23:59:59.123456+00:00"
      },
      "type":"event"
   }
}";

// considering JSONObject matches the Json object structure
JSONObject jsonObject = mapper.readValue(jsonString , JSONObject.class);
```

Then a little bit of [reflection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html) to handle any JSON object fields dynamically:

```
// with parsed JSON to Object in hands
Class<?> clazz = jsonObject.getClass();

for(Field field : clazz.getDeclaredFields()) {
    if(!field.getType().getName().equals("String"))
        break;

    field.setAccessible(true);
    String fieldValue = field.getValue().toString();

    if(fieldValue.startsWith("${"))
        field.set(jsonObject, fieldValue.replace("${", "").replace("}", ""));
    else
        // desired treatment
}
```